# Is is possible to get references from a paper?(e.g., given paper A cites paper B, C and D, i wanna to extract Bibtex of B, C and D from A)

Tags: bibliographies

Is is possible to get references from a paper?
For example, given that paper A cites paper B, C and D, i wanna to extract Bibtex of B, C and D from A. Is is possible to do this conveniently? Thank you for any help!

EDIT: A more concrete example: I have paper A which cites many other papers such as B, C and D. I wanna some ways to directly get bibtex of all these cited papers in paper A.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what exactly you mean by "extract Bibtex of B, C and D from A".

Comment: Some database systems record the references in a paper, sometimes they can be extracted from the database. An example where this definite works is http://adswww.harvard.edu/. http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/ provides references but no means to download them as `.bib` directly, so does http://apps.webofknowledge.com/.

Comment: What I mean is that I have paper A which cites many other papers such as B, C and D. I wanna some ways to directly get bibtex of all these cited papers in paper A.

Comment: Presumably some of the known citation database programmes such as Mendeley, Zotero and EndNote also have a similar option.

Comment: @ytutow Can you tell us which paper A you have in mind?

Comment: @samcarter It is 'gradient-free hamiltonian monte carlo with efficient kernel exponential families'

Comment: @moewe I have tried http://adswww.harvard.edu/ and found that this database does not contain complete ref

Comment: @ytutow You can get the source code from https://arxiv.org/format/1506.02564. Unfortunately this does not contain the .bib file, but you can extract the information from the bbl file and convert it to .bib via http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/

Comment: The information is not in the PDF or, even, the `.tex`, if that's what you're asking. So what a database provides will be the best you can get unless something like Zotero can parse the PDF directly, or you can get the `.bib` or `.bbl` as above.

Comment: @samcarter Thank you! You are really clever!

Comment: A big thank to everyone here for helping me!

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate. The earlier query actually states that the potential input is a bbl file, rather than the formatted pdf file. However, the main issues -- all linked to the loss of meta information -- are exactly the same, regardless of whether the source is a bbl file or a pdf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:**

The source code of the article is available from [arxiv.org/format/1506.02564](http://arxiv.org/format/1506.02564).  Unfortunately this does not contain the `.bib` file, but "only" the `.bbl` file.

**Step 2:**

To extract the desired information from the `.bbl` file, one can try to convert it back to a `.bib` file. This can for example be done with [text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca](http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca)

The result will be something like

```
@article{neal2011mcmc,
author = {R. M. Neal},
journal = {Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo},
title = {{MCMC using Hamiltonian dynamics}},
volume = {2},
year = {2011},
}
```

**Step 3:**

Check the result and correct the output of this automatic conversion. For example the entry shown above should probably changed to `@inbook`.

Comment: This example of a "quasi-automated approach" is, I'm afraid, both well-intentioned and an excellent illustration of some of the things that can go badly wrong with this approach. First, `@article` is definitely not correct as the entry type; it should be either `@inbook` or `@incollection`. Second, the `journal` field name should be changed to `booktitle` and the `volume` field name should be changed to `edition`. Third, the fields `editor`, `address`, `publisher`, and `pages` should all be supplied as well. I strongly suspect one would be better off building the entire entry from scratch.