# Is there any way to import a bbl file to BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref, bbl

Assume I have a `.bbl` file like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[\protect\astroncite{Abramowitz \& Stegun}{1965}]{Abrasteg65}
Abramowitz, M. \& Stegun, I.~A. (1965).
\newblock {\em Handbook of Mathematical Functions}.
\newblock Dover, New York.
...

\end{thebibliography}
```

Is there any efficient way of importing their entries to BibTeX?

Comment: The only automatic tool I know about is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233442/35864. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204121/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203177/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371794/35864,  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233655/35864.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I did search for similar questions, but I miss completely the ones you linked. My bad.

Comment: JabRef only offers "New entry from plain text": https://help.jabref.org/en/NewEntryFromPlainText. We could work on a bbl. You could add a feature request.